# Sprite Atlas not showing in Xcode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, texture-atlas

I've been creating a Sprite game in swift using the Sprite kit. I've declared the project to be of type game. I've created a folder an appended .atlas to the end of it. I've added this folder to my project. The variables I create for an TextureAtlas work great however all the images appear blank inside the folder and the actual sprites have the white box with a red arrow inside. I've seen many tutorials on how to fix this, and the final thing I have yet to do is enable the texture atlas in the build configurations. When following the apple documentation they say enter "sprite" inside of the search yet nothing appears. I've also seen people say to enter something along the lines of "SPRITE_TEXTURE_ATLAS", but still no to avail. If anyone has any advice on how to set this up that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the actual atlas folders had references to the images outside of Xcode causing the pictures to not load correctly at compile time. This is what caused the default white box with an X to appear.